# Postgres schema based replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-10

I have setup streaming replication in postgresql V10 in the production environment. Now for a typical scenario, I would like to know if I can configure replication in such a way that only specified schema gets replicated from master? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html) is for.

However there is no feature to just publish (and subscribe) a single schema. So you will have to list the tables of the schema individually in the `create publication` statement.

There were substantial improvements in logical replication since it was introduced in Postgres 10. You might want to consider upgrading to the current version (13) before you proceed.